# Media queries on Javascript isnt working here

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Why isn't the @media query working here?
how to fix it?
What's wrong with the media queries?

```js
const Size = {
  laptop: "1024px",
  laptopL: "1440px"
}

const Device = {
  laptop: `only screen and max-width: ${Size.laptop}`,
  laptopL: `only screen and max-width: ${Size.laptopL}`,
};

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle `
  body{
    background: url(${BackgroundImage}) no-repeat center center/100% 100% fixed;
  }
  @media ${Device.laptop} {
    body{
      background-size: cover;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Did you miss the bracket after `createGlobalStyle`?

Comment: Media queries are meant to work with CSS. Why are you trying to place them in JS?

Comment: I assume this is https://styled-components.com/

Comment: If you’re going to point out potential syntax errors make sure you’re familiar with tagged template literals, styled components or emotion. OP’s code looks fine on first glance.

Comment: You forgot to warp media queries with parentheses ! Sol => `const Device .... media only and (max-width: ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need round brackets around your max-width and pixel size. Try this:

```js
const Device = {
  laptop: `only screen and (max-width: ${Size.laptop})`,
  laptopL: `only screen and (max-width: ${Size.laptopL})`,
};
```